# Ajax Image Upload And Data Same Form Submit Even Without An Image Selected (Pithyupload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, upload

I am using a ajax data/image upload script called pithyupload, It work great for ajax image and data uploads accross all browsers as it has iframe fallback for ie.
I would like to work if the user decides not to upload and image and just the text data. However, the script does not fire unless it detects and image has been uploaded by the user.

Below I have included the code below, any ideas to work around this?

Ajax form submit

```
    $(document).ready(function (e){
$('#newdata').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault();

//all form data values here//

$(function() {
$('#pithyUpload').pithyUpload({
    url: 'addData.php',
    dataType: 'text', 
    extData: { fullname: fullname, position: position, email: email, selecteddepartments: selecteddepartments, 
     isadmin: isadmin, agentbio: agentbio, editid: editid, type: type, companyid: company, chatlimit: chatlimit
              },
     onUploadSuccess: function(file, data, status, xhr) {


            },
    onFileTypeError: function(file) { }
 })  }); });  });
```

pithyupload jsfile

```
; (function ($) {
$.fn.pithyUpload = function (opts) {
    var $self = this;
    //default settings
    opts = $.extend({
        //properties
        url: document.URL,
        method: 'POST',
        extData: {},//extra data
        maxFileSize: null,
        maxFiles: null,
        allowedTypes: null,//null or array(eg. ['jpg', 'doc'])
        dataType: 'json',//ajax dataType
        fileName: 'pithyUpload',
        trigger: null,//null or 'change'
        //callbacks - if IE, only onNewFile, onComplete
        onNewFile: function () { },
        onComplete: function () { },
        onUploadProgress: function () { },
        onUploadSuccess: function () { },
        onUploadError: function () { },
        onFileTypeError: function () { },
        onFileSizeError: function () { },
        onFilesMaxError: function () { }
    }, opts || {});
    var typeReg = null;
    if (opts.allowedTypes)
        typeReg = RegExp("\.(" + opts.allowedTypes.join("|") + ")$", "i");

    //upload every single file
    function upload_file() {
        if (this._pos >= this.files.length) {
            this._pos = 0;
            opts.onComplete.call(this);
            return;
        }

        //check file type an file size
        var typeTest = true,
            sizeTest = true;

        //check file type
        if (typeReg)
            if (!typeReg.test(this.files[this._pos].name)) {
                opts.onFileTypeError.call(this, this.files[this._pos]);
                this._pos++;
                typeTest = false;
                upload_file.call(this);
            }

        //check file size
        if (opts.maxFileSize)
            if (opts.maxFileSize < this.files[this._pos].size) {
                opts.onFileSizeError.call(this, this.files[this._pos]);
                this._pos++;
                sizeTest = false;
                upload_file.call(this);
            }

        //ajax submit
        if (typeTest && sizeTest) {
            var self = this,
                $self = $(this),
                file = self.files[self._pos],
                fd = new FormData();
            opts.onNewFile.call(self, file, opts);
            for (var key in opts.extData)
                fd.append(key, opts.extData[key]);
            fd.append(opts.fileName, file);

            $.ajax({
                url: opts.url,
                type: opts.method,
                dataType: opts.dataType,
                data: fd,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                forceSync: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (xhrobj.upload) {
                        xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                            var percent = 0;
                            var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                            var total = event.total || event.totalSize;
                            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                            }
                            opts.onUploadProgress.call(self, file, percent);
                        }, false);
                    }
                    return xhrobj;
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    opts.onUploadSuccess.call(self, file, data, textStatus, xhr);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    opts.onUploadError.call(self, file, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                    self._pos++;
                    upload_file.call(self);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function upload_files() {
        var self = this,
            $self = $(this);
        if (typeof FormData == 'undefined') {//IE
            var $iframe = $('<iframe style="position:absolute;top:-9999px;"/>')
                .attr('name', 'pithyUploadIframe'),
                $form = $('<form style="display:none;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>')
                    .attr('name', 'pithyUploadForm')
                    .attr("target", 'pithyUploadIframe')
                    .attr('action', opts.url),
                $input = $('<input type="file"/>').attr('name', opts.fileName),
                $hidden = $('<input type="hidden"/>');
            $iframe._upload_read = false;
            $('body').append($iframe).append($form.append($input));
            for (var key in opts.extData)
                $form.append(
                    $hidden.clone()
                        .attr('name', key)
                        .val(opts.extData[key])
                );
            $input.change(function () {
                opts.onNewFile.call(self, this.value);
                $form.submit();
                $iframe._upload_read = true;
            });
            $iframe.load(function () {
                if(!$iframe._upload_read)
                    return;
                var contents = $(this).contents().get(0);
                console.log(contents);
                var data = $(contents).find('body').text();
                if ('json' == opts.dataType) {
                    data = window.eval('(' + data + ')');
                }
                opts.onComplete(data);
                $iframe.remove();
                $form.remove();
            });
            $input.click();
        } else {
            if (opts.maxFiles)
                if (opts.maxFiles < this.files.length) {
                    opts.onFilesMaxError.call(this, this.files);
                    return;
                }
            self._pos = 0;
            upload_file.call(self);
        }
    };

    if (opts.trigger) {
        if (typeof FormData == 'undefined') {//IE
            return $self.click(function () {
                upload_files.call(this);
                return false;
            });
        }
        return $self.change(function () {
            upload_files.call(this);
        });
    } else {
        upload_files.call($self.get(0));
        return $self;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, perform some validation before sending the data across / firing the pithy function.

```
var myImageFile = document.getElementById("imageFile");
if( myImageFile.files.length == 0 ){
    console.log("no image file selected");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it the pithy function that handles the data/image I just want to adapt the function to fire and upload the data without the need for an image.